# XML to CSV using XMLreader

Tags: c#

I want to convert my XML into a CSV file

"System/Main Chassis/Front Panel; "OMA/LCDprops/LCDobj/lcdaccessstate"; 0->disabled;1->enabled;2->N.A"

Where
 "System/Main Chassis/Front Panel=path of the xml display page in the report"
"OMA/LCDprops/LCDobj/lcdaccessstate=node path(xpath)"
"0->disabled;1->enabled;2->N.A=all the possible values and their meanings for that particular node"

Can someone please let me know the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I am using XMLReader and getting the elements name first. then I am appending all the elements one by one to make it OMA/LCDprops/LCDobj..
next I was thinking of taking it into one array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more simple solution could be be an xsl stylesheet transormation from the xml to text file. You can manage the xsl transformation in C# with **XslCompiledTransform** object if you want

Comment: I was actually adding my comment before you replied I have tried using xsl transform class but while doing that I realized all the changes to achieve what I want had to be done in XSL. I am new to .net and wanted to learn more things in it so I dropped that half way thru